# Visual studio code not working with Xampp

Tags: visual-studio-code, xampp

I am a complete beginner with html. When I run my website via localhost live server function on desktop it works. However when I put it on htdocs, the still runs but I can't edit it. All my files weirdly show as ._index.html, and etc on visual studio.

It says "The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding. Do you want to open it anyway ? "

Comment: Could you please list out your details issues along with images and errors. It  would be better if you do so. If the problem is clear you have high probability of getting answers quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Have you tried any other code/text editor like [Sublime Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YPhF.jpg) or [Notepad ++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/)?

Binary means non-text file which explains why your VS Code cant open the file..
However, There is an Extension for VS Code called [HexDump](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=slevesque.vscode-hexdump).

It Display a specified file in hexadecimal format and from there you can try to resolve the issue with your files.

But i suggest you try a different text/code editor to identify the issue.

HexDump example:

[image: Displaying Hex Data]